# CSS Header alignment on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have two headers which I would like to display on the same line, but one on the left and one on the right. What is the best way to do this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hunterchristian/3XsJF/)

HTML:

```
<h2 style="color: green" style="text-align : center">Approved</h2><h4>Count: </h4>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 11.5pt;
    font-family: Georgia;
    display: inline;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 10px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: you could float it right? http://jsfiddle.net/3XsJF/1/

Comment: `inline` and `margin` don't work well, since `inline` basically prevents the element from having a box. Either use `inline-block` or `block` and positioning.

Comment: you could use `float` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `float` property to each header like:

```
h2 { float: left; }
```

and

```
h1 { float: right }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use float.

```
h2 {
    font-size: 11.5pt;
    font-family: Georgia;
    display: inline;
    float:right;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 10px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3XsJF/8/)

```
<div class="first"><h1 style="color: green" style="text-align : center">Approved</h1><h2>Count: </h2></div>
```